# Como posso colocar efeito de lentidão ao trocar de classe com toggleClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esse código atual que tenho para trocar a classe e fazer o efeito de aparecer e sumir o texto em overflow.

```
$('.toggle_view_item').on('click', function(){
   $(this).siblings('.toggling_item').toggleClass("text-truncate")
   $(this).siblings('.toggling_item').toggleClass("text-wrap")
   
   $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye")
   $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye-slash")
 })
```

Esse é o resultado que a função faz, porém é de forma bruta, queria suavizar a animação:
[image: Esse é o resultado que a função faz, porém é de forma bruta, queria suavizar a animação]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bem, lendo apenas está parte do código não entendi muito, mas acredito que colocando um transition no elemento que está com este toggle resolve (na classe do elemento, não na classe que está sendo usada no toggle)
por exemplo

```
.toggling_item { transition: all 2s ease-in-out; }
```

alguns links uteis:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: também não é possivel animar a propriedade display, então é recomendável animar o atributo opacity.